# Taylor Polynomials and Uniqueness

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider the following proposition. $P_n(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k (x-a)^k $ satisfies :

$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-P_n(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0 $

if and only if $P_n$ is the $n$th Taylor polynomial of $f$ around $a$. I can prove the direction in which we assume $P_n$ is the Taylor polynomial, however the other direction (i.e. showing this is unique) has eluded me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that $P $ and $Q $ are degree $n $ polynomials with 
$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-P(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0,\ \ \ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-Q(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0.$$ It follows that 
$$\tag {*}\lim_{x\to a}\frac {P (x)-Q (x)}{(x-a)^n}=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-Q(x)}{(x-a)^n}-\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-P(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0. $$ Any polynomial can be written as its Taylor polynomial around $a $. So we may assume $$P (x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k (x-a)^k,\ \ \ \ \ Q (x)=\sum_{k=0}^nb_k (x-a)^k. $$Now $(*) $ becomes $$\tag{**}0=\lim_{x\to a}\sum_{k=0}^n (a_k-b_k)(x-a)^{k-n}. $$ By multiplying by different powers of $x-a $ we obtain $a_k=b_k $ for all $k $.

Concretely: the first term in the sum in  $(**)$ is $a_0-b_0$, so if the limit is zero we get that $a_0=b_0$, Now $(**)$ becomes, after multiplying by $(x-a)^{n-1}$, 
$$
0=\lim_{x\to a}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_k-b_k)(x-a)^{k-1}. $$ The first term in the sum is $a_1-b_1$, so if the limit is zero then $a_1=b_1$. This reasoning can keep going until we get that $a_k=b_k$ for all $k$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last point? what do you mean exactly by "multiplying by different powers of $x-a$ we obtain$a_k=b_k$"?

Comment: Additionally, I'm having a little trouble seeing the link between your argument and the theorem. What your argument seems to say is that if we have equation $(*)$ where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials, then they must be the same polynomial. How does that connect back to approximating an arbitrary function $f(x)$ in the original question? thank you kindly for you help.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the additional details! I know most mathematicians value brevity, so I really appreciate fleshing it out. My only lingering concern is for the very last part. What about the terms before $a_n-b_n$? Can we conclude that  $a_k=b_k$ because otherwise for $k$ not equal to $n$ $(a_k-b_k)(x-a)^{k-(n-1)}$ will not have a limit as $x$ tends to $a$?

Comment: You always show equality of the last two. Then that difference will be zero and you start again. Do it in paper for $n=3$.

Comment: I must be missing something simple because in my reasoning you get $x+a_k-b_k=0$ where $x$ represents all the previous terms. Your solutions suggests that x must be zero, because otherwise we can only conclude $a_k+x=b_k$ in the limit. What am I missing?

Comment: I have edited, one had to start from the other side. Like I said, if you had tried with $n=3$ you would have seen what to do.

Comment: Hi, I know it's an old question, but I prefer not to start a whole new question about it.
I don't get why we can multiply by different powers of $(x-a)$.. why is it true? I tried writing the summation when n=3 and all I could conclude is that $a_3 = b_3$ (If I even got it right).
I guess I'm missing very trivial thing and would like if you can explain any further :)

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x-a)=0$, then $\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)^mf(x-a)=0$, since (when the limits exist) the limit of the product is the product of the limits. Start with $(**)$. Multiply by $(x-a)^n$; the limit is still zero, but now all the powers are positive with the exception of $a_n-b_n$ which is multiplied by $1$. So $a_n-b_n=0$. Now go back to $(**)$, and now multiply by $(x-a)^{n-1}$; now every term in the sum is multiplied by a power of $(x-a)$, with the exception of $a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}$, which is then zero. And you keep going like this.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought and wasn't sure it's legit! Thank you! 