# Show that the Taylor polynomial $P_n$ for a $C^\infty$ function $f$ is the unique one to satisfy $ \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-P_n(x)}{x^n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $r>0$ and $f:(-r, r) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an infinitely differentiable function. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define the polynomial
$$
P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k !} x^k .
$$
Then, which of the following statements is/are true:

(a) The sequence $\left\{P_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f$ pointwise in some open interval containing $0$ .

(b) If $J$ an open interval containing $0$ such that the sequence $\left\{P_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $J$, then $P_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $J$.

(c) For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the polynomial $P_n$ satisfies
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-P_n(x)}{x^n}=0
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(\text{Eq-1})$$

(d) For all $n \in N, P_n$ is the unique polynomial of degree $\leq n$ satisfying (Eq-1).

First statement can be eliminated by the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}& x>0,\\0&x \leq 0.\end{cases}$$

Further, I know the convergence of Taylor's polynomial to the corresponding $C^\infty$ function is uniform to say second option is true.

How to deal with option 3 and 4 (uniqueness)? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I would consider $P_n - Q_n \equiv (f-Q_n) - (f-P_n)$ and consider what must be true if the first $n$ derivatives of two polynomials of degree $n$ agree at $0$.

Comment: b) Consider $\frac{1}{1-x}$ on the interval (-1,1)
c) Is equivalent to Peano's reminder
d) If $Q \neq P_n$ then $f(x)-Q(x)$ have a non-zero $k$-th derivative at zero for some $0 \leq k \leq n$ which implies $\frac{f(x) - Q(x)}{x^k} \to c \neq 0$ for minimal possible choice of $k$.

Comment: Duplicate for d): [Taylor Polynomials and Uniqueness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985365).

Comment: @MykolaPochekai Are you sure that the convergence of $1+x+x^2+...+x^n$ to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is not uniform? If so, can you explain a little, thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty much, "uniform on $(-1,1)$" means the convergence of $\sup_{-1 < x < 1} | 1+...+x^n - \frac{1}{1-x}|$ to zero when $n \to \infty$. However the  $\sup ...$ expression is $+ \infty$ for every $n$. Btw, you can draw corresponding plots of corresponding functions in your favorite CAS package if you are still not convinced

Comment: Ya...I got the point, thank you very much. Further, why this argument is not valid for the convergence of $1+z+z^2+...+z^n$ to $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$ for any $z \in \Bbb C$ with $|z|<1$?

Comment: Because "pointwise convergence" and "uniform convergence" are different modes of convergence, I have no deeper explanation. Algebraically to prove pointwise convergence you have to find estimate $|1+z+...+z^n - \frac{1}{1-z}| < h(z,n)$ such that $h(z,n) \to 0 $ when $n \to \infty$, but to prove uniform convergence you have to find estimate $|1+z+...+z^n - \frac{1}{1-z}|<h(n)$ s.t. $h(n) \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$  so you have less freedom (you can't use $z$ in your estimate).

Comment: Geometrically: look on the plots of $1+...+x^n - \frac{1}{1-x}$ in Wolfram Alpha for example ( https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E6%2Bx%5E7%2Bx%5E8%2Bx%5E9%2Bx%5E10+-+1%2F%281-x%29) it is closer and closer to 0 on $(-1,1)$ but there is always a problem in neighborhoods of $1$.

Comment: @MykolaPochekai So are you telling that the convergence of the Taylor series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^n$ to $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$ is not uniform for $z \in \Bbb C$ with $|z|<1$?

Comment: @Riaz Yes, however, it is uniform on $|z| \leq a$ for every $0<a<1$.